# Displaying the Set<String> value in lightning-radio-group

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, radiogroup

Displaying the `Set<String>` value in `lightning-radio-group`

```
"filterlabel": "Age",
"filterValue": ["9-13", "5-8"]
```

From My Controller, I'm getting `filterlabel` and `filterValue` , When i tried to display the `filterValue` in `lightning-radio-group` i'm getting empty radio group button as below.
(the controller will return an array of object, Each object has a Own filter - Dynamic filter)

[image]

```
<lightning-radio-group 
    name="filter" 
    label={sub.filterlabel}
    options={sub.filterValue} 
    type="button">
</lightning-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Options need to be in the specific format. `{ label: 'Sales', value: 'option1' }`.

so

```
 "filterValue": [
    "9-13",
    "5-8"
]
```

should be.

```
 "filterValue": [
    { "label": "9-13", "value": "9-13" },
    { "label": "5-8", "value": "5-8" }
]
```

You can create a wrapper class in apex for that.

```
public class OptionWrapper{
    @auraEnabled
    public string label{get;set;}
    @auraEnabled
    public string value{get;set;}
}
```